# How to create a base that contours text

Tags: text-object

I'd like to take a word and create a thin base that contours the letters and not have any through-holes. I've sketched an example of what I'm looking for.

I'd describe this as a 'skirt' in 3D-printing terms.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the text you have already, make it thinner(z) and larger(x,y), then convert it to mesh and delete the "holes" by hand. i think, there is not automatic tool for that.